# Delphi 7 coreide70.bpl access violation

Tags: delphi

Delphi 7 has been running fine for a long time (months on this machine, many years on others.)

However, although I know of nothing that I changed (and certainly didn't install any components) if I try to run a newly created, simple program,  with one form, while I'm in the IDE, I get an Access Violation at address 006DDDC2 in coreide70.bpl.

The program runs fine outside the IDE.

I'm running no add-ins (like Delphi Speedup...)

Other than completely ripping and re-installing, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is to remove packages from the IDE. Try this out with your vanilla empty app rather than your real app. If that doesn't help I'd move straight to a Delphi reinstall. That really ought to fix it and there's probably nothing to be gained trying to solve the problem with a reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

A rip and re-install solved the problem ... for a while, and then it re-surfaced.

For anyone having the same problem, I have traced this down to something being corrupted in my saved desktops. Since the problem was occurring when I tried to run a program, it would naturally switch to the debug desktop.  Apparently it was corrupted. Saving a new desktop to replace the old desktop resolved the problem.

Comment: I am currently living with this problem as well. Debugger crashes when I hover over some value which requires a dereference, then some internal error, then core70 bpl error.